# Spark - handle blank values in CSV file

Tags: apache-spark, spark-csv

Let's say I've got a simple pipe delimited file, with missing values:

```
A|B||D
```

I read that into a dataframe:

```
val foo =  spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter","|").load("/path/to/my/file.txt")
```

The missing third column, instead of being a null value, has the string null:

```
+-----------+----+
|_c0|_c1| _c2|_c3|
+-----------+----+
|a  |b  |null|c  |
```

I would like to be able to control what Spark does with that missing value.  According to the [CSV Documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/read-csv.html), there is a `nullValue` option:

> nullValue: string that indicates a null value, any fields matching
>   this string will be set as nulls in the DataFrame.

But since I don't have any value there, I can't seem to control it that way.

Short of testing every single field of every single file I read in, is there way to control what spark does with these blanks?  For example, replace it with 'N/A'.

We're using Spark 2.1, if it's relevant.

Comment: I don't think there is an option for that. You can always transform the result whatever way you want. If you need I can give an example for that

Comment: Have you tried either option("nullValue", '') or option("emptyValue", '')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nullValue` and `emptyValue` options do the opposite of your expectation - they allow you to specify values that, if encountered in the source data, should be turned into `null` or `""` (respectively) in the resultant dataframe. For instance, if your input was instead

`a|b|N/A|d`

and you set

`option("nullValue", "N/A")`

you would wind up once again with

```
+-----------+----+
|_c0|_c1| _c2|_c3|
+-----------+----+
|a  |b  |null|c  |
```

More to the point, Spark includes functions for dealing with null values in the class [DataFrameNaFunctions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions). For example, `df.na.fill("N/A")` will replace all `null` instances in string columns with `"N/A"`.